# how to solve redirect url problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: codeigniter, internet-explorer, redirect

My website project is running well in firefox and google chrome but has url problem in IE(IE10). When i do login from IE though username and password is correct, the url remains in login and not to dashboard as expected.Below in controller code for redirect url.

```
$user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
$password = $this->input->post('pass_word');
$user_id = $this->login_model->check_login($user_name, md5($password));

if ($user_id != 0){
    //set session and redirect to dashboard
    $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', $user_id);
    $next_url = $this->session->userdata('next_url');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('next_url');
    //redirect($next_url);
    redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'location');
}else{ 
    $data['login'] = 'Invalid Username/Password!';
    $data['class'] = 'error';
    $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
    redirect('administrator/login');
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong. How am i to solve this? Any help or suggestions is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem.Server time wasn't same as client time. (server time:11:30am, client time:5:30pm)
"Make sure your server’s time is correct. All browsers set cookies based on the client’s time.  IE on the other hand, goes by server time.  If the server’s time is in the past, cookies will expire as soon as they are set thus giving the illusion that your cookie never arrived."
check the link: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/135722/

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `location` with `refresh`

```
redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'refresh');
```

Comment: redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'location');
redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'refresh');
already tried these 2 options but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'location');
```

to

```
redirect('administrator/dashboard' , 'refresh');
```

Just using `location` can sometimes cause problems